# I always get an UndefinedConversionError in Ruby 2.0 while scraping with Mechanize

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, mechanize, iconv

When I try to submit a textarea with Mechanize and Ruby 2.0, I always get an

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+0151 from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1
```

Then I tryied to convert the text with Iconv, I got a similar result:

```
Iconv.iconv("LATIN1", "UTF-8", text)
```

I get this error message:

```
Iconv::IllegalSequence: "őzködik, melyet "...
```

As the text contains east-european characters. What can I do to avoid this kind of inconveniences or how can I convert properly between different encodings?

Comment: can you give the code part,by which you are going to put the text data into the text area box...?

Comment: That char won't convert to latin1 because it doesn't exist in latin1.

Comment: My Ruby program contains the text as a here-document, and the encoding of my Ruby program is set to utf-8 (# encoding: utf-8) If I load the webpage in Opera browser, and I examine the source HTML, the page encoding is really set to ISO-8859-1, and if I simply paste the text which contains the bad character(s) it works, I can submit without error. How can I convert the utf-8 string to ISO-8859-1 / LATIN1? Maybe I can use such codes as in HTML: &#337; (from this tabel http://www.thesauruslex.com/typo/eng/enghtml.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I have found an elegant solution:

```
replacements = [["À", "&#192;"], ["Á", "&#193;"], ["Â", "&#194;"], ["Ã", "&#195;"], ["Ä", "&#196;"], ["Å", "&#197;"], ["Æ", "&#198;"], ["Ç", "&#199;"], ["È", "&#200;"], ["É", "&#201;"], ["Ê", "&#202;"], ["Ë", "&#203;"], ["Ì", "&#204;"], ["Í", "&#205;"], ["Î", "&#206;"], ["Ï", "&#207;"], ["Ð", "&#208;"], ["Ñ", "&#209;"], ["Ò", "&#210;"], ["Ó", "&#211;"], ["Ô", "&#212;"], ["Õ", "&#213;"], ["Ö", "&#214;"], ["Ø", "&#216;"], ["Ù", "&#217;"], ["Ú", "&#218;"], ["Û", "&#219;"], ["Ü", "&#220;"], ["Ý", "&#221;"], ["Þ", "&#222;"], ["ß", "&#223;"], ["à", "&#224;"], ["á", "&#225;"], ["â", "&#226;"], ["ã", "&#227;"], ["ä", "&#228;"], ["å", "&#229;"], ["æ", "&#230;"], ["ç", "&#231;"], ["è", "&#232;"], ["é", "&#233;"], ["ê", "&#234;"], ["ë", "&#235;"], ["ì", "&#236;"], ["í", "&#237;"], ["î", "&#238;"], ["ï", "&#239;"], ["ð", "&#240;"], ["ñ", "&#241;"], ["ò", "&#242;"], ["ó", "&#243;"], ["ô", "&#244;"], ["õ", "&#245;"], ["ö", "&#246;"], ["ø", "&#248;"], ["ù", "&#249;"], ["ú", "&#250;"], ["û", "&#251;"], ["ü", "&#252;"], ["ý", "&#253;"], ["þ", "&#254;"], ["ÿ", "&#255;"]]

def replace(str,replacements)
 replacements.each {|replacement| str.gsub!(replacement[0], replacement[1])}
 return str
end

my_string=replace(my_string,replacements)
```